# How can i get all the days name in the week and all the date in week without saturday and sunday in android?

Tags: android, date

Explanation:
           I want to get the name of the day in week and date of the week without saturday and sunday.Is there any way to satisfy my requirement??

Using below code i got all the date of the week

```
String[] days_si = new String[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            days_si[i] = format.format(calendar.getTime());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < days_si.length; i++) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Days : " + days_si[i].toString());
        }
```

please, help me solve out this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find below how to skip certain day,
and how to get day name (short or full)

```
String[] days_si = new String[7];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    //skip SATURDAY's
    if(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY){
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        --i; //THIS PART TO AVOID EMPTY ARRAY ITEMS
        continue;
    }

    //in your format pattern, use EEE to get short day name
    //or use EEEE to get full name
    days_si[i] = format.format(calendar.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
for (int i = 0; i < days_si.length; i++) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Days : " + days_si[i].toString());
}
```

** more on `--i; //THIS PART TO AVOID EMPTY ARRAY ITEMS`
in an iteration, if a day is Saturday, then the loop will skip without adding value in `days_si[i]`, which will result in an empty array slot, because next loop `i` will be incremented by 1 and so `days_si[i-1]` will remain empty or null.

you may need an array of object (custom object) contains 2 properties
`String dateOfDay` and `String nameOfDay`, use this array to store day date and day name for each iteration in the for loop

if you want your output to be in a single line, ex: **2016-07-19 Tuesday** then skip the custom object part

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the various formatting patterns which the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) provides.

For example:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("u EEEE");
```

will give you the output as

```
Days : 7 Sunday
Days : 1 Monday...
```

Try out the various patterns as per your needs.

---

Regarding the part where you want to skip Saturday and Sunday:- You can add a simple `if` check in your first `for` loop to see if the formatted string which the `format()` method returns contains the strings Saturday or Sunday and if so, do not add them to your string array.